# Dropdown menu - slideToggle challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup, megamenu

Following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $('.menu').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.submenu').slideToggle(1000);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
li, body, a{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  margin:0;
  background:red;
}

.menu{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  height:5rem;
  width:5rem;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  position:relative;
}

.submenu{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:purple;
  position:absolute;
  top:5rem;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='menu'>
    <a href=''>Page 1</a>
    <div class='submenu'>
      <div class='page_title'></div>
      <div class='page_description'></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class='menu'>
    <a href=''>Page 2</a>
    <div class='submenu'>
      <div class='page_title'></div>
      <div class='page_description'></div>
    </div>
  </li>
    
</ul>
```

I am trying to achieve two things in this.

1. When I click on the second link, the first submenu should slide Up and second open should slide down.
2. Here, when I click inside the first submenu after the slide down, it closes up. I want do not want it to close down, but only closes when I click on the same link tag or the next link
3. Alternatively, it will be great, if it can slide up when I click outside of the submenu on the body.

Any assistance is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  (function initSlideToggle() {
    var $menus = $('.menu');

    $menus.find('.submenu')
      .on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
      })
      .hide()
      .end()
      .on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(e.currentTarget),
          $openedSubMenus = $menus.find('.submenu:visible').not($this),
          openThisSubMenu = function() {
            $this.children('.submenu').stop(true, true).slideToggle(1000);
          };

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (!$openedSubMenus.length) {
          openThisSubMenu();
        }
        $openedSubMenus.stop(true, true).slideToggle(1000, function() {
          openThisSubMenu();
        });

      });
  })();

});
```

```css
li,
body,
a {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.menu {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.submenu {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='menu'>
    <a href=''>Page 1</a>
    <div class='submenu'>
      <div class='page_title'></div>
      <div class='page_description'></div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class='menu'>
    <a href=''>Page 2</a>
    <div class='submenu'>
      <div class='page_title'></div>
      <div class='page_description'></div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. But if you see click back again on the link first after clicking link 2, both remains open.

Comment: @jeff Ok, but your description did not say that. So effectively you want to have opened only one at the same time. Will edit.

Comment: yes mate. Thats correct. Could you please, provide a link for me to learn this. For me it goes on top of my head.

Comment: Again I came across another challenge. If I do multiple clicks on these items, it basically goes up and down until it finishes my click numbers.

Comment: @jeff Just try some jQuery tutorials and play a little bit around with jQuery.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp 


If you have specific questions to the code I have provided for you, just ask me for. 

The jQuery functions can be found easily. For instance just search for '.not()  jquery' and you will find infos about that. You could also copy & paste every single javascript line and see what the result is in your browser console, to understand it better

Comment: @jeff yes, that's because .slideToggle() is executed asynchronously and once the execution has been started, it has been added to the execution-queue.
What behaviour do you want to achieve?

Comment: basically, it should stop animation immediately, instead of sliding up and down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184211/discussion-between-gutelaunetyp-and-jeff).